# SQL EXEC sp_MSforeachdb giving error

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create multidatabase query using sp_MSforeeachdb and receiving an error when executing it. There are no view-able syntax errors with SQL SSMS, so I am not sure I am getting this

Here is the SQL Ive written:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb N'IF ''?'' in (''db1'',''db2'')
BEGIN
PRINT ''Use [?]''
PRINT ''DROP FUNCTION uf_EncryptAES;'' 
PRINT ''GO''
PRINT ''DROP FUNCTION uf_DecryptAES;''
PRINT ''GO''
PRINT ''DROP ASSEMBLY MVE_Crypt;''
PRINT ''GO''
PRINT ''CREATE ASSEMBLY MVE_Crypt from ''''C:\MVE_Crypt.dll'''' WITH PERMISSION_SET = unsafe;''
PRINT ''GO''
PRINT ''CREATE FUNCTION uf_EncryptAES(@input nvarchar(4000),@key nvarchar(4000)) returns nvarchar(4000) EXTERNAL NAME MVE_Crypt.[MVE_Crypt.MVE_Crypt].EncryptAES;''
PRINT ''GO''
PRINT ''CREATE FUNCTION uf_DecryptAES(@input nvarchar(4000),@key nvarchar(4000)) returns nvarchar(4000) EXTERNAL NAME MVE_Crypt.[MVE_Crypt.MVE_Crypt].DecryptAES;''
PRINT ''GO''
END'
```

When I run this, I receive the following error:

Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'CREATE'.

The error appears to be on the second create function statement and not the first one, which makes no sense because they are written the same.

I'm using SQL server 2012 Enterprise SP1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is not in your stuff but in `sp_MSForEachDB`.

You are executing a Stored Procedure. Are you sure the you read the parameter as in SSIS and not in the standard way?

I would try using `DB_NAME()` and see:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb N'IF '''' + DB_NAME() + '''' in (''db1'',''db2'')
BEGIN
PRINT ''Use [?]''
PRINT ''DROP FUNCTION uf_EncryptAES;'' 
PRINT ''GO''
PRINT ''DROP FUNCTION uf_DecryptAES;''
PRINT ''GO''
PRINT ''DROP ASSEMBLY MVE_Crypt;''
PRINT ''GO''
PRINT ''CREATE ASSEMBLY MVE_Crypt from ''''C:\MVE_Crypt.dll'''' WITH PERMISSION_SET = unsafe;''
PRINT ''GO''
PRINT ''CREATE FUNCTION uf_EncryptAES(@input nvarchar(4000),@key nvarchar(4000)) returns nvarchar(4000) EXTERNAL NAME MVE_Crypt.[MVE_Crypt.MVE_Crypt].EncryptAES;''
PRINT ''GO''
PRINT ''CREATE FUNCTION uf_DecryptAES(@input nvarchar(4000),@key nvarchar(4000)) returns nvarchar(4000) EXTERNAL NAME MVE_Crypt.[MVE_Crypt.MVE_Crypt].DecryptAES;''
PRINT ''GO''
END'
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the info. That completed the query successfully, but it did not print the information needed. I think I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! Through further testing, I determined that the script did not like the section in (''db1'',''db2'')

So I replaced it with

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb N'IF ''?'' in (Select database_name from databaselist.dbo.sometable)
```

So instead of naming the databases, I used a select statement to pull the databases from a table where I have the databases listed. This worked perfectly.